# How can I login to Domino via Ajax?

Tags: ajax, lotus-domino

How can I login to Domino via Ajax? without using DOJO?

Answer (score 0):

I found the code. I have published it here:
http://domino-mobile.blogspot.com/2011/02/authenticating-to-domino-via-ajax-in.html

Answer (score 0):

ok, jquery can?

```
$("#login_form").submit(function() {
$("#login_result").removeClass().addClass('process').text('checking....').fadeIn(1000);
var xhr = $.post($("#login_form").attr('action'), { username:$('#username').val(),password:$('#password').val(),rand:Math.random() } ,function(data) {
        if((xhr.getResponseHeader("Last-Modified")!="") & (xhr.getResponseHeader("Last-Modified")!=null)) {
            // login correct
            $("#login_result").fadeTo(200,0.1,function() {
                $(this).html('redirect.....').removeClass().addClass('success').fadeTo(900,1,
                function() {
                    document.location=document.location.href;
                });
            });
        } else {
            $("#login_result").fadeTo(200,0.1,function(){
                $(this).html('login incorrect ...').removeClass().addClass('error').fadeTo(900,1);
            });
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

**#login_form** - your custom form such as `<form method="post" action="/names.nsf?login" id="login_form">`