# Use stored NSUserDefaults to sign into a web site

Tags: ios, objective-c, authentication, xpages, afnetworking-2

In my iOS app I have my user authenticate against our Domino server and store the username and password. I have some web pages that I want the user to see and am loading them in a UIWebView. However, every time I try to go to the page I am being challenged for authentication. I *think* I need to send a post to the server with my username and password but I am not sure how to do that?

Comment: That's more an iOS or ObjectiveC question

Answer (score 2):

I've never done that with iOS, so take this with a grain of salt, but I think there are generally two ways to do it:

1. You can likely pass the UN/password combination along as HTTP Basic authentication in each request. I believe it's the case that Domino will honor those credentials even when session auth is enabled.
2. If you're using session auth, you can do what you intimate: POST to a Domino URL containing the ?Login command (typically, "/names.nsf?Login" is a good choice) with Username and Password parameters (along the lines of [How can I login to Domino via Ajax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4962331/how-can-i-login-to-domino-via-ajax) ). The resultant value of a successful login will contain an authentication token cookie (typically DomAuthSessId or LtpaToken, depending on whether or not you're using SSO). By including that in the Cookie header in future requests, you should be able to continue the login.

Comment: Almost. You need to add a rule in the internet sites to allow for basic auth. And be sure to only use https

Comment: Are you sure? I just tried a curl using a Basic auth username+password on a site without any "Override Session Auth" rules and it acted as the user properly. In any event, I second the HTTPS advice.

Comment: Not fully sure. The documentation suggests so.

Comment: I am going to try adding the internet site rule and basic authentication using https. I think the 2nd solution is more robust and I would like to work on that in the future. One additional question. I have a log in page that I present to the user in iOS and I store their information there. Would it be easier to use the OpenNTF.org login control (http://www.openntf.org/main.nsf/project.xsp?r=project/Xpages%20Dojo%20Login%20Custom%20Control) and then let it just store the cookie in my app?